# Implementing background live location in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can we implement background location tracking in react native?
i don't want to use expo-location as i am looking for react native packages.

i have used @react-native-community/geolocation watchPosition but i know it will not work while our app is in background

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you track background geolocation with React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54811976/can-you-track-background-geolocation-with-react-native)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-native-background-geolocation` for location tracking and use `react-native-background-fetch` for awaking app in the background.